# Adding Hint Text to two input fields in jQuery with same code

Tags: jquery, html

I have one `input` field that I add hint text using jQuery (HTML5 `placeholder` is not an option here).

It does what I want, like so:

```
$("#reportMailerCustomFrom").change(
    function() {
        if ($("#reportMailerCustomFrom").val() == "") {
            $("#reportMailerCustomFrom").css("color", "#999");
            $("#reportMailerCustomFrom").val("required");
        }
    }).click(
    function() {
        if ($("#reportMailerCustomFrom").val() == "required") {
            $("#reportMailerCustomFrom").val("");
            $("#reportMailerCustomFrom").css("color", "#355F85");
        }
    }).blur(
    function() {
        if ($("#reportMailerCustomFrom").val() == "") {
            $("#reportMailerCustomFrom").val("required");
            $("#reportMailerCustomFrom").css("color", "#999");
        }
    });
```

I want to do this with a second `input` field, but I don't want to duplicate all the code and simply change `reportMailerCustomFrom` to `reportMailerCustomSubject`.

I have tried combinations of using `$("#reportMailerCustomFrom, #reportMailerCustomSubject")`  to other combos using `this` keyword to no avail.

What is best way for this?

Comment: it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7JaDZ/1/

Comment: Go ahead and mark that as answer.  Like an idiot, I didn't put the '$' next to `this`.  Had Java style in my head.

Comment: posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#reportMailerCustomFrom, #reportMailerCustomSubject").on('change blur', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == "") {
        $this.css("color", "#999");
        $this.val("required");
    }
}).click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == "required") {
        $this.val("");
        $this.css("color", "#355F85");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7JaDZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/UqgmD/) using a class, that way no matter how many fields you have you don't have to change your selector on the jquery (and it won't get out of hand with multiple IDs)

```
<input id="reportMailerCustomFrom" class="validateme" type="text"></input>
<input id="reportMailerCustomSubject" class="validateme" type="text"></input>

$(".validateme").change(
    function() {
        if ($(this) == "") {
            $(this).css("color", "#999");
            $(this).val("required");
        }
    }).click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "required") {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).css("color", "#355F85");
        }
    }).blur(
    function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val("required");
            $(this).css("color", "#999");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can simplify it further by combining the handlers for `change` and `blur` using `.on()`.